# Symfony pagerfanta - can't translate the text in final pagination

Tags: symfony, translation, pagerfanta

I'm trying to translate from english the next and previous in pagination.
I've tried creating normal *pagerfanta.cs.yaml* with `Previous: "Předchozí" Next: "Následující"` and pagerfanta even has its own translations so it should work by itself, but copying the original *pagerfanta.cs.xliff* to the translations folder doesn't work either.
In services.yaml I have:

```
parameters: 
    locale: 'en'
```

and in translation.yaml:

```
 framework:
    default_locale: cs
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

Symfony debug toolbar also doesn't even catch any translations should take place.
Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install `pagerfanta/twig` package in order to use translatable templates. Then create a new config file at **config/packages/babdev_pagerfanta.yaml** containing

```yaml
babdev_pagerfanta:
    default_view: twig
    default_twig_template: '@BabDevPagerfanta/twitter_bootstrap5.html.twig'
```

By selecting `twig` as `default_view`, the translations are going to be handled properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  {{ pagerfanta(pager, 'twitter_bootstrap4', { prev_message: 'Vorherige', next_message: 'Nächste'}) }}
</div>
```

in some cases you may directly inject your translation